# Problema con consulta de Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Tengo la siguiente consulta que me da un error, pero no consigo descubrir lo que falla.

```
INSERT INTO entradas VALUES(NULL, `3`, `6`, `titulo cualquiera`, 
`Contenido de entrada`, CURDATE();
```

Este es el error que marca:

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Aprendizaje_PhP\Blog_PHP\BD\conexion.php:23 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Aprendizaje_PhP\Blog_PHP\BD\conexion.php(23): PDO->exec('INSERT INTO ent...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Aprendizaje_PhP\Blog_PHP\crear.php(31): Conexion->ejecutar('INSERT INTO ent...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Aprendizaje_PhP\Blog_PHP\BD\conexion.php on line 23

Esta es la tabla entradas en phpmyadmin

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la estructura de la base de datos usada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: puedes agregar el error que te marca y la estructura de la tabla "entradas" para descartar que sea por un tipo de dato

Comment: Asi rapido veo que usas comillas invertidas para encerrar los valores, deben ser comillas simples o dobles. Por otra parte te falta cerrar el paréntesis de la sentencia. Por lo demás, lo veo correcto.

Comment: También, tu campo `id` es **autoincrement**, por la cual no es necesario colocar `NULL` como primer valor en la inserción :)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si tu campo ID está definido como AUTO_INCREMENT no es necesario colocar el NULL en el primer campo

```
INSERT INTO entradas (usuario_id, categoria_id, titulo, descripcion fecha)
 VALUES( `3`, `6`, `titulo cualquiera`, `Contenido de entrada`, CURDATE());
```

Igual te recomiendo usar la sintaxis larga de INSERT para tener mas control en tus campos, es algo que personalmente me gusta hacer, tambien verifica el tipo de dato con el que tienes definido tus campos de usuario_id y categoria_id, si son de tipo INT las comillas no son necesarias

```
INSERT INTO entradas (usuario_id, categoria_id, titulo, descripcion fecha)
 VALUES( 3, 6, `titulo cualquiera`, `Contenido de entrada`, CURDATE());
```

Igualmente note que faltaba cerrar el parentesis de `VALUES`, verifica los tipos de dato de tus columnas y que coincidan con las variables que mandas